# How should I interpret this sentence? (the meaniing of the word "secure")

Tags: word-usage, meaning

I am not sure about the meaning of the word "secure" in the sentence below.

> The purpose Christopher Columbus's journey was to find a way to safely bring black pepper from Asia and secure the kitchens of Europe.

"Secure" means 'to manage to get money or achieve something, often something difficult', so in the sentence can I interpret the sentence into that he took a journey to find a way to supply large amounts of pepper to Europe?

Comment: Where did you get this from? It's a slightly odd way of using "secure" (what's *meant* here is obviously *...and **arrange for a secure reliable supply** [of pepper] for the kitchens of Europe,* or perhaps ***secure / preserve / establish** the **reputation** of European cuisine*. But I suggest you *don't* try to use "secure" like this (it doesn't really work unless we assume a context where the kitchens of Europeans were facing an "existential crisis" if they couldn't get pepper - which even *metaphorically*, is a bit of a stretch).

Comment: @FumbleFingers It looks like it's from an EFL lesson: https://duckduckgo.com/?q="secure+the+kitchens+of+Europe" The text seems fairly good but it does have a few odd turns of phrase in it like "Sorry for them, but they are all wrong."

Comment: I'm not convinced it's On Topic to ask about the meaning of text written by what I would now be prepared to bet any money is a ***non-native speaker source***, even if that source is in fact part of an accredited test. I simply refuse to believe that any native speaker worth his salt would ever choose such "awkward" phrasing, whatever the purpose of the "test".